# Codeigniter website showing error 404 on Google Virtual Instant Live Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, apache2

When I go open up my Codeigniter website on my localhost using Wamp and XAMPP, both works. But when I move it to Ubuntu on Google Cloud, it only works for the first page, afterward, it shows the error when going to another page.

I'm using:

Codeigniter ver 3
Apache2
php7.3

Does anyone know what might have caused this?

[Other Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xSbS.png)

Answer (score 0):

It would be ideal if you check first the **class** name and the **record** name that both should be title case (start with a **capital** letter).

So if the class name is 'controller.php', the file name needs to be 'Controller.php', otherwise, **CodeIgniter** will throw a 404 error.

In **localhost** it probably won't be obligatory, yet in **server** it will check every one of these standards, else it can't distinguish the correct class name.

Comment: I checked that and all my controller class start with a capital letter

Comment: Also, the error page doesn't seem to be a CI error page