# URL module perfectly working on localhost, but not working on web server

Tags: php, codeigniter

The followingURL module is working

```
http://localhost/webnew/wms/directs/main.php?_modid=&_mod=&del=18
```

but can't run it on the server like this:

```
http://......../wms/helpmes/main.php?_modid=&_mod=&status=0&no=1
```

why??

How can I run on the server normally like localhost?

I use code igniter.

Comment: It shows a 404 error or which error is going to display?

Comment: May be this answer will help you :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387536/codeigniter-website-showing-error-404-on-google-virtual-instant-live-server/60387578#60387578

Comment: it show 404 Not Found nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu), sir

Comment: `/webnew/wms/directs/main.php` is not the same as `/wms/helpmes/main.php`, so why would we assume they both work?  Please clarify your question, it does not make a lot of sense as it is.

Comment: I'm sorry I gave the wrong example.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file config/config.php please make sure you have set `permitted_uri_chars` like below.
`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@\=';`

And also please make sure `rewrite module` is on in your server.
for apache server you have to do like below cammand.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo vi /etc/apache2/

sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

In your apchae config file you have to write like this

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>

AllowOverride All

</Directory>
```

And then restart your server.